# suggestion on convolution calculation

Tags: fourier-transform, convolution

What is usually the best way to calculate the integral $$\int_{R^2} f(\vec y)f(\vec x-\vec y)d^2\vec y = ?$$ with Fourier transformation or other useful method? Here $x=\Vert \vec x\Vert$.

Comment: Please double check your question. What is the meaning of "Please note that f is a radially symmetric function of " ?? Are you sure that $f(\vec{x})=f(x)$?

Comment: Why the mathematica tag?

Comment: Thanks for commenting! yes I am sure that $$f(\vec x)=f(x)$$, that is, f(vector x)=f(size of x), and by this, I mean f is a radially symmetric function: it does not depend on the polar angle, and is only dependent on the size of the position vector. I thought Mathematica could solve this problem, but myself could not.

Comment: I think you want to say $f(||\vec{x}||)$ only because $f$ is a function of one parameter only, not several. Using your notations, $f(\vec{x})$ is meaningless.

Comment: For mathematica, see https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/